# how to parse XML file

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I am new in Iphone App development . And I am implementing Google Weather API in my Application. I Use a tutorial code, it use NSXMLParser for parsing. I remove the Tutorial code in below methods. I using this Google API http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=nabha

now what I do to get the output. current temperature, high temperature, low temperature etc.

Any Hints and Solution really appreciated.

thanks

my methods are.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {


}





    2012-07-25 19:20:14.654 XML[4555:f803] Processing Element: xml_api_reply
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
Processing Element: weather
Processing Element: forecast_information
Processing Element: city
Processing Element: postal_code
Processing Element: latitude_e6
Processing Element: longitude_e6
Processing Element: forecast_date
Processing Element: current_date_time
Processing Element: unit_system
Processing Element: current_conditions
Processing Element: condition
Processing Element: temp_f
Processing Element: temp_c
Processing Element: humidity
Processing Element: icon
Processing Element: wind_condition

   etc......
  2012-07-25 19:20:44.042 XML[4555:f803] No Errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML) for parsing short XML fragments. Getting the current conditions temperature would look something like this (untested):

```
RXMLElement *root = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=nabha"]];

RXMLElement *currentConditions = [root child:@"current_conditions"];
RXMLElement *tempC= [currentConditions child:@"temp_c"];
NSLog(@"temperature (C): %@", [tempC attribute:@"data"]);
```